# C++11: How to create an enum class inside an class that behaves like a sub class?

Tags: class, c++11, data-structures, struct, enums

To explain my problem I posted an example below. The code in this form is not tested so there might be some syntax mistake in it. As I have to work with a lot of registers in an integrated circuit with their addresses which can be remapped, it would be very useful to create structures like that below. Is there some trick to create these structures? As this example does not work the way I want it because foo requires a Country object and Country::Europe::Italy is invalid as parameter.

```
// I want to create a structure like this
class myClass {
public:
    class Country {

        enum class Europe {
            England,
            France,
            Germany,
            Italy
        };

        enum class Asia {
            China,
            Japan
        };

    };

    // Here I want to make sure, that the method is only
    // called with a Country element and e.g. Italy should
    // behave like a Country object. Actually it should behave
    // as if it is derived from Country.
    int foo(Country c);

};



int main() {
    myClass myC();

    // Exemplary call of the method foo
    myC.foo(myClass::Country::Europe::Italy);
}
```

Comment: `enum Class` is not a class. So it cannot be derived from `Country` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proper example using registers and a better explanation would have been better. I guess you want to remap from one register name to another. A suggestion:

```
class Register {
public:
  enum class UserName {
    REG_IO0,
    REG_MEM1
  };
  enum class CPUName {
    REG_INT0,
    REG_INT1
  };
  void setMapping(UserName from, CPUName to); // store the mapping
  CPUName getMapping(UserName name) const; // retrieve the mapping
private:
  std::map<UserName, CPUName> m_registerMap;
};
```

If you want you could implement get/set methods for the registers in that class if you store the indexes/adresses of the registers. Either use templates or overload them for different data types.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `enum class` to achieve your goal. However, you can use a `namespace` with a set of hardcoded `constexpr` objects:

```
struct Country 
{ 
    int _id; 
};

namespace Countries
{ 
    namespace Europe 
    {
        constexpr Country Italy{0};
        constexpr Country France{1};
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
myC.foo(Countries::Europe::Italy);
```

Comment: You can actually do that with enum instead of `struct Country` in c++17

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly use an enum type as a function or constructor argument, restricting the caller to using that enumeration. 
The thing you can't trivially do is combine multiple enum definitions in the way that you have suggested.

You could write several constructors, one for each of the enums Europe, Asia, etc, but that would be work, especially if you have a number of functions that need to take these enums as arguments.

--OR--

You could define one big enum, and define fixed value separators for each subgroup, so you can compare the enum value against these guard values to identify the subgroup. You lose the sub-grouping if you do that. You could use c++11 constant enum initialisers to construct enum value members in subclasses for each continent - but note these are only available for `enum class` from c++17 (so I am using a nested class trick to provide the member namespace enforcement - in c++17 you could have `enum class Location` - you can write this in c++11 but you can't then do the const initialisers). The values follow the above rule of separators, but callers have to indirect through the subclasses to get the names.

```
class Country
{
  class Location {
    enum Value { 
      None =0,
      Europe = 0x0100,
      Asia =   0x0200,
      //etc
    };
  };

  struct Asia {
    const Location::Value Japan { Location::Asia + 1 };
    //etc
  };
  struct Europe {
    const Location::Value UnitedKingdom { Location::Europe + 1 };
    //etc
  };
  // etc
};
```

Then you could have

```
class myClass {
public:
  myClass(Country::Location::Value v);
};
```

And call it with

```
myClass instance(Country::Asia::Japan);
```

-- OR --

You could define another structure who's only purpose is to take the various enumerations and convert them to a pair of values for the continent and country index. You could then use that structure as your function parameter, and allow auto-conversion from that structure. This means you only do the conversion once, and callers to your code are not impacted. You could use the guard ranges such that you don't need to explicitly store the continent code, just the raw country number would be unique across all your enums.